# Why do I need to use a const reference parameter in a << overloading function when using an overloaded post-decrement operator?

Tags: c++, reference, operator-overloading, constants

I have the following `<<` overloading function:

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, HW4& rhs)
{

    for(int i = 0; i < HW4::size; ++i)
    {
        output << rhs.array[i] << "    ";
    }

    return output;
}
```

And I also have this post-decrement overloading function:

```
HW4 HW4::operator--(int)
{
    HW4 temp = *this;
    int hold;
    for(int i = 0; i < size/2; ++i)
    {
        hold = array[i];
        array[i] = array[size - i - 1];
        array[size - i - 1] = hold;
    }

    return temp;
}
```

I don't understand why

cout << object2-- << endl << endl;

won't compile unless I change the `<<` overloading function to have a `const` reference parameter like this

```
ostream& operator<<(ostream& output, const HW4& rhs)
```

Comment: `operator--` returns a temporary. A temporary cannot bind to a non-const lvalue reference.

Comment: If `<<` is changing the value of `rhs` You're going to weird-out a lot of people. Use the `const` , Luke.

Answer (score 4):

`HW4::operator--(int)` returns by value, then what `object2--` returns would be a temporary object which can't be bound to an lvalue reference to non-const.

On the other hand, temporary object can be bound to lvalue reference to `const`. That's why making `operator<<` taking `const HW4&` works. Conventionally `operator<<` is supposed for outputting only, it shouldn't change the object passed; so you *should* declare `operator<<` taking `const HW4&` as the parameter.